# How to upload a sound clip to SoundCloud

Tags: android, soundcloud

In my android app I'm recording an audio file which I then want to share to SoundCloud and `GET` the url of that. What's the best way to do so?

I can share through an explicit `Intent` but how can I get the track url then? shall I use the java wrapper to upload the audio?

Answer (score 2):

```
File myAudiofile = new File("/path/to/audio.mp3");
Intent intent = new Intent("com.soundcloud.android.SHARE")
  .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(myAudiofile))
  .putExtra("com.soundcloud.android.extra.title", "Demo");
  // more metadata can be set, see below

try {
    // takes the user to the SoundCloud sharing screen
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // SoundCloud Android app not installed, show a dialog etc.
}
```

Refer:

- https://github.com/soundcloud/android-intent-sharing/wiki/Explicit-intent-sharing

Comment: what if I want to get back the link of the sound ?

Comment: Made like this https://github.com/soundcloud/android-intent-sharing/wiki/Standard-sharing-flow, but nothing happen. All application got the file, but when i choose SoundCloud nothing happen.